# Robolectric unable to get resource

Tags: java, android, maven

When I'm trying to use Robolectric I got following errors (I can't paste more, because I'm new here). How can I solve it?

Downloading: org/robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.pom from repository central at

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.robolectric:android-all:pom:4.3_r2-robolectric-0' from repository sonatype

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/

Error transferring file: Connection refused: connect

**UPDATE:
I solved my problem. Using proxy caused that.**

Comment: Please explain how did u achieved

Comment: Please share the answer, so users with the same problem could use it.

Comment: @majkel Please give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should write correct proxy settings for maven.
Create settings.xml file in your ~/.m2 directory

```
<settings>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host></host>
            <port></port>
            <username></username>
            <password></password>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

You can read additional info here https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html